# Storing IEnumerable<X> so that it can be used by multiple webparts on a page

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

Another is this possible question:  I have 4 webparts that read in a csv file, process it and create a IEnumberable that is used for graphing.  Right now the webparts each read in and process the file.  I was wondering if there is a way i could save off the result with a time stamp and then have the webparts use this (provided the timestamp doesn't indicate that it is old) stored version.  I know a web service might be a way to solve this but that would be out of scope....so ideally looking for something simple where you could store it then pull it out/cast.  Any ideas welcome :)

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straight forward caching question, so I'd use HttpRuntime.Cache in the first instance.

Here's a scenario from Tobias Zimmergren: http://zimmergren.net/technical/web-part-caching-a-simple-approach

Comment: Easier than what i had just come up with which was to create a connectable web part that would process the CSV and serve up the IEnumerable on request.   Many thanks!